# How can I get the absolute position of a shape in a PDF using TallComponents PDFKit

Tags: c#, .net, pdf

I'm trying to identify the location of particular shapes in a PDF using TallComponents PDFKit 4 so that I can position other shapes relative to them. (i.e., 10 pt below and 40 pt to the right of an identified image)

Each `Shape` in PDFKit has `X` and `Y` coordinate properties, but the origin of the coordinate system seems to change based on nested shapes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code extracts all graphics on the first page as shapes:

```
Stream stream;
... // initialize stream
Document document = new Document(stream);
ShapeCollection shapes = document.Pages[0].CreateShapes();
```

Shapes inside the collection all inherit from class `ContentShape`. Specializations include `Textshape`, `FreeHandShape`, `ImagesShape` and `ShapeCollection`. The latter allows for nesting as you mention. The coordinate system of each shape is defined by that of the containing `ShapeCollection` multiplied by its own `ContentShape.Transform` property.

So in order to calculate the absolute coordinates (or device coordinates) you need to concatenate all the transforms from the root down to the actual shape.

The following code writes the coordinates of paths to the output:

```
Matrix transform = new Matrix(); // start with identity
write(shapes, transform);

void write(Shape shape, Matrix transform)
{
   if (shape is TallComponents.PDF.Shapes.ContentShape)
   {
      ContentShape contentshape = (ContentShape)shape;
      // calculate the transformation matrix of the user space
      Matrix newTransform = contentshape.Transform.CreateGdiMatrix();
      newTransform.Multiply(transform, MatrixOrder.Append);

      if (shape is FreeHandShape)
      {
         write((FreeHandShape)shape, newTransform);
      }
      else if (shape is ImageShape)
      {
         write((ImageShape)shape, newTransform);
      }
      else if (shape is ShapeCollection)
      {
        // recurse
        ShapeCollection shapes = (ShapeCollection)shape;
        foreach (Shape s in shapes)
           write(s, newTransform);
      }

      // ignore other shapes
   }
}
```

The following methods write all points of the FreeHandShape to the output in an SVG-like format using absolute coordinates:

```
void write(FreeHandShape freeHandShape, Matrix transform)
{
   write(freeHandShape.Paths, transform);
}

void write(FreeHandPathCollection paths, Matrix transform)
{
   foreach (var path in paths)
      write(path, transform);
}

void write(FreeHandPath path, Matrix transform)
{
   foreach (var segment in path.Segments)
   {
      if (segment is FreeHandStartSegment)
      {
         var s = (FreeHandStartSegment)segment;
         Console.Write("M {0} ", write(s.X, s.Y, transform));
      }
      else if (segment is FreeHandLineSegment)
      {
         var s = (FreeHandLineSegment)segment;
         Console.Write("L {0} ", write(s.X1, s.Y1, transform));
      }
      else if (segment is FreeHandBezierSegment)
      {
         var s = (FreeHandBezierSegment)segment;
         Console.Write("C {0} {1} {2} ",
            write(s.X1, s.Y1, transform),
            write(s.X2, s.Y2, transform),
            write(s.X3, s.Y3, transform));
         }
      }

      if (path.Closed)
         Console.Write("Z ");
   }
}

string write(double x, double y, Matrix transform)
{
   PointF[] points = { new PointF((float)x, (float)y) };
   transform.TransformPoints(points);
   return String.Format("{0} {1}", points[0].X, points[0].Y);
}
```

**UPDATE:**

The following method writes the ImageShape to the output in an SVG-like format using absolute coordinates. Note that it draws the image as a red rectangle since it only demonstrates the position of the corners. Also note that it transforms `(0, 0)` as the lower-left corner instead of `(X, Y)`. The reason is that properties `ContentShape.X` and `ContentShape.Y` are read-only properties that return the position after transformation. So if we would transform `(X, Y)` as well, it would be transformed twice.

```
  private void writeImageShape(ImageShape image, Matrix transform)
  {
     Console.Write("M {0} ", writePoint(0, 0, transform));
     Console.Write("L {0} ", writePoint(0, image.Height, transform));
     Console.Write("L {0} ", writePoint(image.Width, image.Height, transform));
     Console.Write("L {0} ", writePoint(image.Width, 0, transform));
     Console.Write("Z");
  }
```

For simplicitly, this code does not take into account the Rotate and CropBox properties of the page that define an initial transformation. [Here is a working code sample](https://github.com/tallcomponents/ShapesToSvg) that converts all paths and images (as rectangles) to SVG using absolute (device) coordinates.

Comment: The logic you describe appears to work for `FreeHandShape`, but not for `ImageShape`, which is the specific thing I'm trying to find the position of. I'm getting negative and off-page coordinates for image X and Y positions using this approach. (I've verified that the transforms produce exactly the same results as the working sample for `FreeHandShape`s.)

Comment: Can you please provide the PDF

Comment: I have added code for ImageShape. It dumps the 4 corners to Console. The trick is that you should transform [(0,0), (0,height), (width height), (width, 0)]. Don't add X and Y. See explanation in answer. I also updated the working sample on github.